# Quartz: wait another job

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I have 2 jobs, one runs every hour, the second one runs once per day. Theoretically every job's execution could be longer than hour (or even several hours).

These jobs mustn't be executed at the same time.
So I should implement some checking, if the another one is running, then wait when it finishes, and start execution. How can I implement this (using Quartz)?

**Edit:**
*@DisallowConcurrentExecution* doesn't help, because it skips execution without waiting when another job finishes.

Comment: Is `synchronized` OK for you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set to a QUARTZ JOB to start only when an another JOB finished, stopped?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22861365/how-to-set-to-a-quartz-job-to-start-only-when-an-another-job-finished-stopped)

Comment: @BorisShchegolev yes, it is

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt I've updated the question

Comment: @TarasKohut What makes you think that it skips the execution? [What happens to jobs affected by Quartz DisallowConcurrentExecution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5835109/what-happens-to-jobs-affected-by-quartz-disallowconcurrentexecution)

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt ok, looks like it doesn't skip the execution but postpones it. The only issue is that this annotation tells Quartz not to execute multiple instances of a given job definition, it means that I can't use it for synchronizing several Jobs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a similar problem and solve it using a TriggerListener to put jobs in a queue, based on [JobChainingJobListener](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.1/org/quartz/listeners/JobChainingJobListener.html)